# Await result of recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, async-await

This solve function sorts elements in an array by their decreasing frequency. If two elements have the same frequency, they will be sorted by increasing value.

This works fine as long as the input array is not as long. If it is a bit longer, it throws a *Cannot read property 'forEach'* error.

So I made the function async to wait for the recursive function to actually return the result.. but this immediately gives me `Promise {<pending>}`

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

```
function sameCountSort(arr) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let done = true;
    let result = [...arr];
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i++) {
      if (result[i][1] === result[i + 1][1] && result[i][0] > result[i + 1][0]) {
        let temp = [...result[i]];
        result.splice(i, 1);
        result.splice(i + 1, 0, temp);
        done = false;
      }
    }
    if (!done) {
      sameCountSort(result);
    } else {
    resolve(result);
    } 
  })
}

async function solve(arr){
  const numberCount = {};
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (numberCount[arr[i]]) {
      numberCount[arr[i]]++;
      } else {
        numberCount[arr[i]] = 1;
      }
  }
    
  const sortedNumberCountAsArray = Object.entries(numberCount).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
    
  const internallySorted = await sameCountSort(sortedNumberCountAsArray);
    
  let result = [];

  internallySorted.forEach((entry) => {
    result = [...result, ...new Array(entry[1]).fill(parseInt(entry[0], 10))];    
  })
  return result;  
}

solve([ 0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 8, 10, 12, 14, 17, 21, 21, 22, 26, 34, 34, 36, 38, 40, 40, 44, 45 ]);
```

Code looked like this before. The first call of solve works, the other one doesn't.

```
function sameCountSort(arr) {
    let done = true;
    let result = [...arr];
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i++) {
        if (result[i][1] === result[i + 1][1] && result[i][0] > result[i + 1][0]) {
            let temp = [...result[i]];
            result.splice(i, 1);
            result.splice(i + 1, 0, temp);
            done = false;
        }
    }
    if (!done) {
        sameCountSort(result);
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}

function solve(arr){
  const numberCount = {};
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (numberCount[arr[i]]) {
      numberCount[arr[i]]++;
      } else {
        numberCount[arr[i]] = 1;
      }
  }
    
  const sortedNumberCountAsArray = Object.entries(numberCount).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
    
  const internallySorted = sameCountSort(sortedNumberCountAsArray);
    
  let result = [];

  internallySorted.forEach((entry) => {
    result = [...result, ...new Array(entry[1]).fill(parseInt(entry[0], 10))];    
  })
  return result;  
}

solve([2,3,5,3,7,9,5,3,7]);
solve([ 0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 8, 10, 12, 14, 17, 21, 21, 22, 26, 34, 34, 36, 38, 40, 40, 44, 45 ]);
```

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous in your code, so using a promise doesn't makes sense in your code.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to `resolve(sameCountSort(result))` inside the `if (!done)`

Comment: same result @msbit

Comment: Can you remove the asynchronous stuff and make a runnable snippet that demonstrates your original problem (before you introduced async stuff?)

Comment: Added the code how it looked before

Comment: @Nils And why did you change anything? Just use the working, synchronous version.

Comment: I think the issue with the original code is that if `done` is not set in the main loop of `sameCountSort`, it will return `undefined`, so `internallySorted.forEach(...)` will cause an error. Try `return(sameCountSort(result))` instead of just `sameCountSort(result)` in that function (similar in spirit to my suggestion in the `Promise` version).

Comment: @msbit you are right, there was just a return missing. And in the if statement in line 6 I had to wrap the two elements in the > comparison into parseInt. Thank you, now it all works!

Comment: @Nils, can you show the expected output? There's still a lot of room for improvement in this code.

Comment: @Thankyou Yes, you are right. This is actually not a good solution for this problem. What you pass in is an array of integers, for example [2, 4, 6, 2, 2, 1, 4] and the output should order them in a way that the most frequent ones come first. 2 is the most frequent, so that goes first into the resulting array. If the frequency is the same, you sort them from smaller to higher value. So for that example the result should be [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 6]. That could probably be achieved with way less code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that code can definitely be simplified.  Perhaps something like this:

```js
const solve = (ns) =>
  Object .entries (ns .reduce ((a, n) => ({...a, [n]: (a[n] || 0) + 1}), {})) 
    .sort (([v1, c1], [v2, c2]) => (c2 - c1) || (v1 - v2))
    .flatMap (([v, c]) => Array (c) .fill (Number (v)))

console .log (
  solve ([2, 3, 5, 3, 7, 9, 5, 3, 7]) .join (' ')
)
console .log (
  solve (
    [0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 8, 10, 12, 14, 17, 21, 21, 22, 26, 34, 34, 36, 38, 40, 40, 44, 45]
  ) .join (' ')
)
```

With this input

```js
solve ([4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5])
```

we start with the `reduce` call to turn it into a value-count object like this:

```js
{"1": 1, "2": 1, "3": 3, "4": 3, "5": 1}
```

Then `Object.entries` converts it to this:

```js
[["1", 1], ["2", 1], ["3", 3], ["4", 3], ["5", 1]]
```

We then sort this in a single pass, by subtracting the counts, and if that's zero subtracting the values.  (Because counts should be descending, that subtraction is left from right.  Because values should then be ascending, we subtract right from left.)  We now have this:

```js
[["3", 3], ["4", 3], ["1", 1], ["2", 1], ["5", 1]]
```

And finally, we map each of those value-count pairs into an array that is `count` long each index holding `value`.  Because we use `flatMap` these arrays are flattened into a single one, to yield this:

```js
[3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you @Scott this is very helpful. Only flaw: if the initial array contains a 0 it is lost somewhere.. when you try this [ 0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 8, 10, 12, 14, 17, 21, 21, 22, 26, 34, 34, 44, 38, 40, 40, 36, 45 ] the zero is gone in the result.

Comment: Actually, the bug was more serious than that.  It dropped the first entry every time.  It's fixed now.  (I was missing the accumulator parameter in the `reduce` call.)